# SQL-Oracle- Compare 3 columns across two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: Tables A has columns 1, 2, 3. Table B has columns X, Y, Z.  All columns are VARCHAR2(10).

I need to compare columns 1 to X, columns 2 to Y, and columns 3 to Z, looking for all cases where 1,2,3 <> X,Y,Z.

I have searched a number of articles on SO, and have not found what I'm looking for.

Any assistance appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You should always show what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks codeNinja....I will in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.1, a.2, a.3, b.x, b.y, b.z
from a cross join b
where
a.1 <> b.x and
a.2 <> b.y and
a.3 <> b.z
```